# How we add a custom function to \Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation

Tags: magento2, layered-navigation

I overrode the \Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation block and added a custom function, but while rendering the function in view.phtml, it shows a function not found error. Any once can help me.

My Navigation.php

```
<?php
 namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Block;
 class Navigation extends \Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation
 {
  public function customMethod() {
   ...code
  }
 }
```

My di.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
 <preference for="Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation" type="Vendor\ModuleName\Block\Navigation" />
</config>
```

Calling from .ptml file, that overrides the .phtml file related to layer navigation

```
<?php $block->customMethod(); ?>
```

Comment: My first guess is that you missed the class constructor. You might also have forget to di compile after doing your modification.

Comment: can you please mention , how we add the constructor

Comment: why using preference ? just go with viewModel..

Comment: Hi @Pawan , can you please provide sample code